# Remove extra space from ConstraintLayout inside ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-constraintlayout

I use ConstraintLayout, Guideline and ImageView together for responsive view. I am getting extra spacing on the top and bottom on ImageView. I tried `android: adjustViewBounds` and `android:  scaleType` but it didn't work How can I clear it out?

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".20"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/right_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".80"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/left_guideline"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/right_guideline"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:src="@drawable/logoo" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I used your layout:

[image]

Then added this to ImageView:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

And this is the result:

[image]

So just add `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` in your imageView and that should do it.

Comment: I fixed it  using android: scaleType = "centerCrop" and changing the layout_constraintDimensionRatio. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want the view to take all space then, Could you try **scaleType** in your ImageView.

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

ImageView

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/left_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/right_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:src="@drawable/logoo"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />
```

If this is not what you want, then please comment.

Comment: fitXY breaks the original picture size

Comment: It has to do with the image aspect ratio. By default, the system keeps the original aspect ratio of the image source. Which in most cases does not exactly match the layout or dimensions specified in the layout. Therefore,

Either change the size of the image to fit the specified layout, or
Use android:scaleType to fit the image. For example, you can specify android:scaleType="fitXY"

In your case, fitXY is breaking the original picture size.